# Алгоритм работы cookies

Tags: cookie

Подскажите, по какой логике определяется, какие куки должны быть переданы на сайт.

Насколько я понимаю, то domain.com и www.domain.com считаются равнозначными и куки у них общие.
Я запутался в разнице между domain.com и .domain.com. На что указывает точка перед доменом? При открытии сайта user.domain.com должны быть переданы куки устанавливаемые для domain.com или .domain.com?

Comment: `При открытии сайта user.domain.com должны быть переданы куки...` - с обоих должны. А по старым правилам только с `.domain.com`.

Comment: @Visman , вот да, я считал, что в поддоменах должны быть видны куки только от .domain.com. А эта логика для некоторых сайтов не работает. Что за правила и когда они изменились?

Comment: Вот тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php в описание параметра `domain` указано: `Задание поддомена (например 'www.example.com') сделает cookie доступными в нем и во всех его поддоменах (например w2.www.example.com). Для того, чтобы сделать cookie доступными для всего домена (включая поддомены), нужно просто указать имя домена (т.е. 'example.com'). Старые браузеры, следующие устаревшим нормативам » RFC 2109, могут требовать ТОЧКУ перед доменом, чтобы включались все поддомены.`

Answer (score 1):

[rfc6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)

> Насколько я понимаю, то domain.com и [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) считаются равнозначными и куки у них общие.

**Нет**.
Куки установленные с указанием домена `domain.com` будут видны на `domain.com` и на всех его поддоменах (например: `www.domain.com`, `www.corp.domain.com`).
Куки установленные с указанием домена `www.domain.com` не будут видны на `domain.com`.

> На что указывает точка перед доменом?

Раньше она указывала на видимость установленной куки в поддоменах домена установки. Теперь она не нужна (смотрите ответ на 1й вопрос), но ошибки не вызывается.

> При открытии сайта user.domain.com должны быть переданы куки устанавливаемые для domain.com или .domain.com?

И те, и другие.

**P.S.** Чтобы кука устанавливалась строго для текущего домена, следует оставить параметр *Domain* пустым при ее установке.